# 404 - Category not found joomla

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla3.0, article

Joomla 3 return 404 when try open url, etc

site.com/index.php/en/rolaplus-en-gb

Article with alias **rolaplus-en-gb** exist.

Other url work fine!

Or how open article over id?

Comment: This quesiton is a bit hard to understand but  I think you will be better off getting good answers at the dedicated joomla.stackechange.com site [joomla.se].

Comment: Check the language plugin settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You setup simple addresses in Global Configuration?

To open articje over id use

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=20
```